# XML parsing (NeTEX format)

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I have a bus fare information available as an xml file from this location

[Bus data from DfT website](https://data.bus-data.dft.gov.uk/fares/dataset/997/)

I was trying to find a way of getting the

1. Bus stop names
2. Atco codes
3. Bus stop zone that it belongs to
4. Fare for that zone

that are accessible in the tag 'ScheduledStopPointRef'.

A sample xml is here

https://data.bus-data.dft.gov.uk/fares/dataset/997/download/

Is there a way to do this using the library Elementree or any others or do. have to traverse the xml file using multiple nested 'for' loops.

A test code that 'sort of' works is as per below

```
tree = ET.ElementTree(file=/path/to/file.xml)
root = tree.getroot()
children = root.getchildren()
for child in children:
    for a in child:
        for b in a:
            for c in b:
                for d in c:
                    if 'FareFrame' in c.tag:
                        for e in d:
                            print("E->", e.text)
                            for f in e:
                                if ('Name' in f.tag):
                                    print("F->", f.text)
                    
                                elif ('members' in f.tag):
                                    for g in f:
                                        print("G tag ->" , g.tag)
                                        print("G->", g.text)
```

Expected output

[image: Bus stop details]

Please advice.

Comment: share the xml (or a **valid** subset of it). based on the xml share the expected output

Comment: @balderman - can you advice how please rather than marking the question down? The link takes you to the page from where the xml can be downloaded to view. The required output has been hinted by Jack Fleeting.

Comment: What is the current situation? You still need help with the XML? If you do - upload a doc and explain what you need from it.

Comment: @balderman - as mentioned in my comment to Jack's solution below, his code takes the JSON from the webpages itself and theres no correlation between the link and the xml, hence I am back to square 1, trying to find someone who can help parse the xml. By the way - I have a snippet of the xml for your info.

Comment: It's great that you have posted xml snippet. We are getting closer...Now remove it and upload a **valid** xml document.

Comment: @balderman - I am unable to upload a file hence have specified a link which has the file. Can you please help with this?

Comment: Based in the xml example in this [link](https://data.bus-data.dft.gov.uk/fares/dataset/997/download/) - what is the exact expected output?

Comment: As mentioned in my question above  - 
1. Bus stop names
2. Atco codes
3. Bus stop zone that it belongs to
4. Fare for that zone

Something like

Stop Name, ATCO, Farezone ID, Farezone Name 
Friarage Road, atco:040000004914, fs@Aylesbury, Aylesbury
Bus Station, atco:040000004658, fs@Aylesbury, Aylesbury
Pearson Close, Aylesbury, atco:040000004402, fs@Oxford_Road/College, Oxford Road/College

Answer (score 3):

Give the below a try (bus.xml is the file in the link)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse('bus.xml')

points = root.findall('.//{http://www.netex.org.uk/netex}ScheduledStopPoint')
for idx,point in enumerate(points,1):
  print(point.attrib['id'])
  print(point.find('{http://www.netex.org.uk/netex}Name').text)
  print(point.find('{http://www.netex.org.uk/netex}TopographicPlaceView').find('{http://www.netex.org.uk/netex}Name').text)
  print(f'--------{idx}----------')
print('Done.')
```

output

```
--------1----------
atco:040000004658
Bus Station
Aylesbury
--------2----------
atco:040000004402
Pearson Close
Aylesbury
--------3----------
atco:040000004918
Churchill Avenue
Aylesbury
--------4----------
atco:040000004917
Aylesbury College
Aylesbury
--------5----------
atco:040000004412
Upton Turn
Stone
--------6----------
atco:040000004410
Long Furlong
Stone
--------7----------
atco:040000004408
Village Hall
Stone
--------8----------
atco:040000004406
The Rose & Crown PH
Stone
--------9----------
atco:040000004404
The Bugle Horn PH
Stone
--------10----------
atco:040000004416
New Road
Dinton
...
```

Comment: Thank you @balderman. I got the principle and had to tweak this a bit to extract what I need.

Comment: Glad I managed to help. Please accept the answer.

Comment: I am curious as to why you marked me down though?

Comment: Why do you think I marked you down? It was not me.

Answer (score 1):

The date you are looking for (if I understand you correctly) is dynamically loaded in json format, not xml. One of the ways to get to it is:

```
import requests
import json

req = requests.get('https://data.bus-data.dft.gov.uk/api/app/fare_stops/?revision=2457')
data = json.loads(req.text)

#once you have the data, extract the target information:
features = data['features']
for feature in features:
    print(feature['properties']['common_name'],feature['properties']['atco_code'])
```

Output:

```
Southfield 040000002345
Dadbrook 040000002429
Pearson Close 040000004402
The Bugle Horn PH 040000004404
The Rose & Crown PH 040000004406
```

etc.

Comment: I thought this is XML question .. Is there a json version of the document as well?

Comment: @balderman It was indeed an XML question; maybe I missed something, but I could only find the data in JSON.

Comment: Ah this is interesting - by clicking the link I pasted above, I am taken to the webpage for DfT for a specific bus route and there is no mention of aJSON anywhere on the page, however inspecting the source of the page gives the link you mention - https://data.bus-data.dft.gov.uk/api/app/fare_stops/?revision=2457. Is there anyway to translate the link I have to the one you found?I ask because there are many routes I am looking into and hence need an automated way.

Comment: @Ananth Not really sure; there must be some lookup table that correlates the two. There is also the possibility of bulk-downloading all the data at once: https://data.bus-data.dft.gov.uk/downloads/

Comment: Thanks @JackFleeting, I downloaded All Fares Data and its a zipped file containing .xml files with fares information for all routes :(. Will reach out to the help teams in DfT to see if they can guide in a lookup. if not I will have to stick to multiple 'for' loops for now unless someone else offers a solution.